# mingw makefile compile error windows

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, mingw

hey guys i'm trying to run the following command:

mingw32-make -f makefile.mingw

everything seems to go fine until after about 3 minutes when i get the following error:

https://images.weserv.nl/?url=i.imgur.com/J7ojYju.png&fnr

The Error is on the left and on the right is the makefile.mingw, what exactly is the problem been trying to get this to work for a while. Thanks

link to make file: https://mega.co.nz/#!GI8kAAgC!I0YPQwroHHJokjoYIZfQADcEYxlG_x0MLTi1pi9CCFI

Comment: Attaching the makefile in question might make this question possible to answer.  For example, in the screen shot it looks like the make is failing at line 137, and being able to see line 137 and all the lines around it would be useful

Comment: Hi, i have uploaded the makefile to mega.co.nz link is in original post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSL development package is not installed.

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty sure i have it installed, i extracted and compiled it in my deps folder openssl-1.0.1e, is there a step I'm missing? new to all this trying to learn as i go.

Comment: I double checked and it seems its all there and i have the lib paths in the makefile all set correctly just unsure whats going on.